# how to create a timer on a video with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timer

I wrote the code like this, and the play button works but the timer does not.

```
<input type="button" id="play" onclick="videoplay();" value=">"/>
```

....

```
<span id="timer">0%</span>
```

....

```
  function videoplay() {
      var video = document.getElementById("video");
      var button = document.getElementById("play");
      if (video.paused) {
          video.play();
          button.value = "||";
          var timer = getElementbyId("timer");
          var update = setInterval(function () {
              timer.textContent = Math.round(video.currentTime / video.duration * 100) + "%";
          }, 500);
      } else {
          video.pause();
          button.value = ">";
          if (update)
              clearInterval(update);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
timer.innerText = Math.round(video.currentTime / video.duration * 100) + "%";
```

Comment: innerText? how about something more firefox and less IE?

Comment: should be using jQuery so we don't have to give a flip.

Comment: it's totally worth 100kb of code so that you can use ".html()" instead of ".innerHTML"...